# Rails 4.2 getting segmentation fault while running tests at active-support

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am trying to build **Rails** from source for the latest stable (4.2) version from the branch 4-2-stable; however I am getting a segmentation fault at 'activesupport' for rake tests.

The details of error log are as below:

> Platform I am trying on: Ubuntu 14.10 Rails Version: 4.2.3 Ruby
>   Version: 2.2.2 & 2.1.6 (on both versions getting same trace)

Log:

> ** Invoke test (first_time)
>
> ** Execute test
>
> /home/test/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.6/bin/ruby -w -I"lib:test"
>   -I"/home/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib" "/home/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb"
>   "test/**/*_test.rb"

Run options: --seed 36135

## Running:

................................................................................................................................................................................  Segmentation fault

rake aborted!

> Command failed with status (139): [ruby -w -I"lib:test"
>   -I"/home/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib" "/home/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb"
>   "test/**/*_test.rb" ]
>
> /home/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/testtask.rb:108:in
>   `block (3 levels) in define'

Can anyone provide any pointers so as to fix this?

Comment: Thanks Daniel for the edits/corrections!

Comment: In addition to the above problem details; I am getting this specific issue on Power system (ppc64le).

Comment: I am also getting this error when I have binding.pry in a loop while running test. Did you solve it?